# API response 404 not found Handling

Tags: javascript, axios

I am working on a project with API. API response is 404 not found. I need to handle this status code without a new page. I want to add an `window.confirm("not found")`. However, I couldnt do that, because when API says 404 there is no response so I couldn't check the response. How can I do that without using new page? How can I handle that? Here is my response code:

```
 const response = await instance.get(`?q=${q}&appid=${appid}`);
  if (!response) {
    console.log("ceren");
  }
```

It never prints "ceren". I tried `response ===""`, `response ===null`, `response.data===null`, and so on

Comment: Is instance from Axios? That _throws_ on a non-2xx status code: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#handling-errors

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes it is axios. When I console.log(response.status) it prints 200 but not print 404

Comment: The promise is _rejected_ for a 404, so with await that becomes a thrown error you need to catch. Read the example in the linked docs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe   Thank youuuu I did this style
 catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.response.status);
      if (err.response.status === 404) {
        window.confirm("City not found!");
      }
    })

Answer (score 0):

The response object is never `null`. It's an object that, along with many other keys, includes the `status`. Moreover, if the request fails, it will throw an error (due to the `await`, though outside of this function it will be a Promise rejection), so you can just catch that:

```
return instance.get(`?q=${q}&appid=${appid}`).then(/*...*/).catch((error) => console.log('Request failed!'));
```

Or, if you must use an `await`:

```
try {
  const response = await instance.get(`?q=${q}&appid=${appid}`);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Request failed!');
}
```